# add textview as a sublayer of an image ios swift

Tags: ios, swift3, uiimageview, textview, catextlayer

```
let ss = CATextLayer()
  ss.frame = rect
  ss.backgroundColor = UIColor.blue.cgColor
  ss.foregroundColor = UIColor.cyan.cgColor
  ss.string = mytextView.text
  myImage.layer.addSublayer(ss)
```

I am trying to add an editable textview as a sublayer of an imageview.the problem is, i am not able to edit and also not able to add gesture recognisers for this textlayer. How can i make this textlayer do exactly what a textview does.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just use `UITextView` or `UITextField` and add it as subview to the `UIImageView`, something like:

```
let textView = UITextView()
//configure text view like you want
//add constraints or size it as you want
myImage.addSubview(textView)
```

Remember `UIImageView` is just another subclass of `UIView` so you can add subviews to it like for a regular `UIView`.

---

Going on to what you are dealing with, since some of the views you add are `CALayer`s and some will be `UIView`s or subclasses of both (for instance `UITextView` is `UIView` subclass)

I would add two properties to your class:

```
var addedViews = [Any]()
var undoStack = [Any]()
```

I know this is not very Swift like since you can put anything into these two `array`s but still.

Then when you create a new `layer` or `view` you also add it to `addedViews` array:

```
let layer = CAShapeLayer()
layer.frame = CGRect(x: 30, y: 30, width: 100, height: 100)
layer.backgroundColor = UIColor.red.cgColor
layer.transform = CATransform3DMakeRotation(0.2, 0, 0, 1)
addedViews.append(layer)
```

So `addedViews` array will hold references to all the views you added, so when you undo you can do just the following:

```
if let viewLayer = addedViews.last {
    if let view = viewLayer as? UIView {
        view.removeFromSuperview()
    } else if let layer = viewLayer as? CALayer {
        layer.removeFromSuperlayer()
    }

    undoStack.append(viewLayer)
    addedViews.removeLast()
}
```

If you then want to redo the change you do the same thing but you get the last view from `undoStack` like so:

```
if let viewLayer = undoStack.last {
    if let view = viewLayer as? UIView {
        self.view.addSubview(view)
    } else if let layer = viewLayer as? CALayer {
        view.layer.addSublayer(layer)
    }

    addedViews.append(viewLayer)
    undoStack.removeLast()
}
```

Comment: I did the same. But the problem is i am using cashapelayers also as sublayers of the same image.When i undo the last layer, the subview is causing error.

Comment: You do what? Can you please explain one more time, I have no idea what `cashapelayers` is and what you mean by `undo the last layer`

Comment: i am making an image editer. So i am adding layers over image. Its. having undo and redo functionality. So when i do the undo function, the subview and sublayers are acting differently. I am removing the last added layer, but subview is not removed.

Comment: Why not have an array of all views added - could be both views and layers and then when you need to undo, you just get last one added and remove it

Comment: I am doing it like that only. I am removing the layer like this,  var c  = documentImage.layer.sublayers?.count sublayerarray.append(documentImage.layer.sublayers![c! -1])
           Myimage.layer.sublayers?.remove(at:c! - 1)

Comment: You use `sublayerarray.append(documentImage.layer.sublayers![c! -1]) ` for undo functionality? so you can add it back in?

Comment: It is ok, just trying to understand what you are trying to do...will try to give you a solution in about an hour

Comment: ok, i. think the problem is that i am using calayer and sublayer simultaneously

Comment: I am doing the same. but the problem is i how will you add a textview with these layers and do the same undo and redo.

Comment: I showed you how, just add it to addedViews when you add it like i did above for the layer, it can hold layers and views

Comment: Check the undo and redo functionality notice when we get the viewLayer we first check if it is of type UIView or CALayer and do the right thing in both cases